# sharedpreference and favorite list, i cant copy array

Tags: android

i am making an application with favorite function that user can add an item in favorite list and i have a listActivity that shows favorite items ;
i store favorite situation in sharedpreferences with this code

```
    boolean[] favorite;
String[] storyTitle;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    storyTitle = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.storyTitles);
    favorite = new boolean [storyTitle.length];
    SharedPreferences appPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);



    for(int x=0;x<storyTitle.length;x++){
        String str ="subject_"+ String.valueOf(x);

        favorite[x]= appPref.getBoolean(str, false);
    }

}
```

when user click to add to favorite i have a method that add item to favorite by making tat item true
its all ok to now ; but when i want to show ListActivity with favorite items by below code ; if one of my items were false ; its error unexpectedly and quit application

```
    String[] storyTitles;
String[] favorite; 
int c=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
storyTitles=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.storyTitles);
favorite= new String[storyTitles.length];
doFav();
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,favorite));


}
public void doFav(){

int c=0;
SharedPreferences appPref = getSharedPreferences("Preference", MODE_PRIVATE);
for( int i=0 ; i<storyTitles.length;i++){
    String str ="subject_"+String.valueOf(i);
    boolean s = appPref.getBoolean(str,false);
    if(s){
    favorite[c]= storyTitles[i];
    c++;


    }

}
```

what's the problem?
if i comment this part app has no error

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,favorite));
```

Comment: what's the error in Logcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

favorite array might have null variable if there are less true than its count.

```
public void doFav(){

int c=0;
SharedPreferences appPref = getSharedPreferences("Preference", MODE_PRIVATE);
Vector<String>tmp = new Vector<String>();
for( int i=0 ; i<storyTitles.length;i++){
    String str ="subject_"+String.valueOf(i);
    boolean s = appPref.getBoolean(str,false);
    if(s){
    tmp.addElement(storyTitles[i]);
    }
}
favorite = new String[tmp.size()];
tmp.copyInto(favorite);
}
```

Comment: the problem was favorite[] as you told i read about Array list and vectors and solve my problem with your answer, thanx a lot <3

Answer (score 0):

You should probably share your stack track.. that might shed more light on the issue..

issue is probably on the String array String[] favorite; that might null.. so either handle the null in the adapter but its not custom adapter in your case you have to handle it by some other technique...

or the problem might be user may not have marked any of the item as favorite so you might be getting no item to copy in your favorite array as a result null array so again handle the null case

Comment: i use an ArrayList and add elements into it , my problem solved , as you said the problem was String[] favorite